# How to make image bigger in gridview

Tags: android, gridview

I trying to show two column gridview with images. The problems that I faced are:

- How to show bigger image ... to fit in size on gridview?

I have tried with different properties on `ImageView.ScaleType`. Currently is *CENTER_CROP*.
This is `grdiview.xml` which I use

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.1" >   

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:columnWidth="80dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"  
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"     
        android:verticalSpacing="4dp" 
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"    
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"        
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"  
        android:gravity="center" >      
    </GridView>             
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the imageview and textview in `tables.xml`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/tableview" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ColPhoto"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ColName"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/ColName"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"        
    android:gravity="center"
     />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ColName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ColPhoto"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"       
    android:gravity="center"       
    android:text="" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And the `getView`

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tables, null); 
        }

        // ColPhoto
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ColPhoto);
        imageView.getLayoutParams().height = 80;
        imageView.getLayoutParams().width = 100;
        imageView.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
```

I missing something and didn't understand what exactly. Also this is the current look. The actual size of the image is 120x120

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the imageView , you can give the following values in layout.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/grid_item_icon"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I trying to achieve. Thank you!